# Python pymysql placeholder breaking using WHILE column IN (set) query

Tags: python, mysql, string, pymysql

I am using pymysql to query a MySQL database using placeholders.  It works well.  I have a query which raises a warning because of the way that the string is handled when the parameters are loaded into the query :

My sample code:

```
thing_ids = "1, 2, 3, 4"
list_notes = db_get_list("SELECT n.note_id, n.note_info, ... FROM note n, contact c WHERE n.note_created_by=c.contact_id AND n.note_on_thing_id IN (%s)", (thing_ids, ))
```

and db_get_list is:

```
def db_get_list(self, sql, args=None):
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql, args)
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

The warning raised is:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:323: 
Warning: (1292, u"Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '1, 2, 3, 4'")
```

I have done some debugging with MySQL on the console.  When I run the query ending:

```
WHERE .... AND n.note_on_thing_id IN ('1, 2, 3, 4')
```

I get the warning.  When I run the query ending:

```
WHERE .... AND n.note_on_thing_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

(no quotes) there is no warning.

How can I pass the argument to cursor.execute() and ask it in this case NOT to wrap the query with 'quotes' (every other time I want to pass it the same as it does today!).

I have seen the other % options in the documentation, e.g. %d, %g - but these only seem to work when the variable is an integer type not a string type.  The string will always be a string with comma separated integer numbers in it (they represent primary key IDs of a column).

Comment: "The string will always be a string with comma separated integer numbers in it (they represent primary key IDs of a column)." Sounds like you are use comma separated values in a column in a table.. if you are using comma separated values you should normalize your data because the IN operator can't selected on comma separated values.. if you can't change the data you need to use MySQL's `FIND_IN_SET` function that function is designed to work on comma separated values..

Comment: Thank you!  I have changed the query to use FIND_IN_SET and not IN () and it's no longer erroring.